# How to highlight all first child upon any first child hover and so on?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover, parent-child

I have a set of parents and childs div. How do I make all first child of each parent to set its opacity to 1, when any of the first child is on hover while every other has its opacity set to 0.25? Also the same for the 2nd, 3rd and 4th child of each parent.

For example, there is a set of 3 rows (parent), each with a set o 4 boxes (child), how do I make every second box of each row highlighted when the second box on any row is hovered, and every other child not highlighted?

Picture of what I expect to happen:

[image]

```css
.child {
  background: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.grandparent:hover .child {
  opacity: .25;
}

.parent .child:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to achieve this setup, is to make each `.parent` a vertical column, rather than a horizontal row.

Then you can use:

```
.grandparent:hover .child {
  opacity: .25;
}
```

to lowlight all the `.child` divs... and

```
.parent:hover .child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

to re-highlight the `.child` divs in the `.parent` column being hovered over.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.grandparent {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
width: 214px;
height: 156px;
padding: 2px;
}

.parent {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
flex-wrap: wrap;
width: 50px;
height: 156px;
}

.child {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: grey;
}

.grandparent:hover .child {
  opacity: .25;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">

<div class="parent">
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure CSS way, you can use `transform` and `rotate` to do this:

```css
.child {
  background: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  opacity: .25;
}

.parent .child:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.grandparent {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -ms-transform-origin: 10% 100%;
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-transform-origin: 10% 100%;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that every other child still has to get its opacity set to 0.25. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Interesting idea! I think the CSS could be modified a bit to highlight entire columns, like the OP's demo image. [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/wsz7ff6o/).

Comment: Ok! That will deal with this case! Thanks! But the real case is bit more complicated, a bar chart, I will post that then and ask for help.